# как обьясьнить поисковикам что сайт один на разных доменных зонах

Tags: seo

Есть сайт который работает доменных зонах .ru и .com но поисковики отмечают содеражание страниц как копии друг друга, как сделать без склейки зеркал чтобы поисковии воспринимали их как единое целое и индексировались оба сайта одинаково не мешая друг другу

Comment: Проверьте руководство Гугл Страницы с идентичным контентом https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать канонический url в теге `link`

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/dresses/green-dresses" />
```

или в http-заголовке:

```
Link: <http://www.example.com/downloads/white-paper.pdf>; rel="canonical"
```

Подробнее: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru

Comment: И в результате вы именно склеите сайты. Здесь hreflang нужно использовать, если сайты ориентированы под географически разную аудиторию.

Comment: @LeshII, автор не сказал, что сайты на разных языках. Но можешь написать отдельным ответом для этого случая.

Comment: нет склейки наоброт я пытаюсь избежать, нужно ведь чтобы обе зоны индексировались, неуженли поисковики не придумали на этот счет ничего? ведь технически сайт может находиться в нескольких доменах с тем же контентом